# CSS prev next button show at middle of image

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please tell me How can I show the icon in the middle of the image left and right side?

**I tried many solutions but they not worked.**

```css
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #2874f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%" (click)="open_slider()">
  <a class="slide">></a>
  <img style="" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN.jpg">
  <a class="slide"><</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` to `img and .slide` for `vertical align`. And use `text-align: center;` to parent div for `horizontal align`.

**Here is the working snippet.**

```css
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #2874f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; text-align: center;" (click)="open_slider()">
  <a class="slide">></a>
  <img style="" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN.jpg">
  <a class="slide">
    <</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Image moved left side I want an image at center with vertical-align of icon center.

Comment: `Image moved left side` , Sorry didn't understand. 
Can you show me a picture that you want ?? @ShahRushabh

Comment: (1) Image center horizontally.

Comment: (2) Next prev icon center horizontal and vertical

Comment: How carousel showing button left and right side in middle.

Comment: I update my answer please check now. @ShahRushabh